# Did Hector vanish while Miguel ran to Mama Coco?

Tags: plot-explanation, coco

So, in this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84635/why-did-miguel-hurry-to-tell-coco-about-hector) we learned that Miguel ran to Mama Coco, since she was the only one whose memories were valid to keep Hector "alive" in the dead world.

However, when Miguel arrives to his house, at least to me it seems that, if not about to die, Mama Coco clearly doesn't recognize anyone anymore. We don't know when that behavior starts, but considering what's going on with Hector in the dead world (he's almost gone), Mama Coco completely forgets everyone a couple of seconds after the sunrise, including Hector.

So, what happened between the moment she forgets him and the moment Miguel starts to sing "Remember Me"? It could easily be like 2 or 3 minutes. Did Hector vanish and then got back to "life"?

Comment: We don't know what happens to a soul when they vanish, Hector says as much. So, your assessment could be possible.

Comment: I'd think not because Miguel is now aware of Hector and has memories of him from the path in the story, there are memories to keep him alive.  I can't remember the film in full to pick out points, but hopefully this could form the basis of an answer if there's evidence to back it up.

Comment: @gabe3886 please read the linked question.